# Using library extensions with TypeScript + requirejs

Tags: three.js, requirejs, typescript

I'm currently messing around with THREE.js and socket.io to make a little game - I'm wanting to use the OrbitControls extension for THREE.js (i've used it before in a non-TS project) for camera controls.

The problem is that the client can't seem to find it (it compiles fine):

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

at line:

```
this.cameraControls = new THREE.OrbitControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);
```

I'm including in my TS file using:

```
///<reference path="../typings/threejs/three-orbitcontrols.d.ts"/>
import OrbitControls = require("three-orbitcontrols");
```

At the bottom of my three-orbitcontrols.d.ts file I have my usual export that I seem to need at the bottom of some typing files:

```
declare module 'three-orbitcontrols' {
    export=THREE.OrbitControls;
}
```

But i'm not sure if this is the right format, I've tried a few things like directing requirejs to the right file in the config (since the filename is a bit different):

```
paths: {
    "three-orbitcontrols": "three.orbitcontrols"
}
```

Interestingly, after compiling with Gulp (using AMD), three-orbitcontrols does not appear in the require at the top of the resulting .js file.

My question is: how do you properly include an 'extension' library for a library you already have with TS and requirejs? Is there some form of merge I need to do? Do i need to manually merge the d.ts and js files? (I hope not!)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how do you properly include an 'extension' library for a library you already have with TS and requirejs?

Since you are calling `THREE.` here : `new THREE.OrbitControls`. You need to put `import OrbitControls = require("three-orbitcontrols");` on `THREE` so:

```
import OrbitControls = require("three-orbitcontrols");
THREE.OrbitControls = OrbitControls;
```

Note: There isn't an *idiomatic* way of doing this since there isn't an idiomatic way that JavaScript libraries do this. The solution here is *specific* to your use case and this extension.